# Retrofit2 json object problem begin object but was string at line

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

How I can handle Json object response like this one:

```
{
    "beginLetter": "",
    "checksDiscount": false,
    "lastInvoice": "0",
    "multiplePaymentFeature": false,
    "printingOnline": false,
    "returnMessage": "logged Out Successfully",
    "success": true,
    "waterFeature": false,
    "waterfeature": false
}
```

I keep getting error message says:

> begin object but was string at line..

Comment: share your pojo class

Comment: the problem is not in my class, i used retroft2 1000 time, but in this response the json object is wrapped in a String, i tried to use something like new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(),StaffLoginResponse.class),, but no hope

Comment: Check the response code you are getting from the server, most probably you are not getting a JSON response, it must an HTML page.